# Enclose last two fields of a CSV file in quotes

Tags: linux, csv, awk, sed

I have a following csv:

```
column1, column2, column3
1, 03-12-2017, some text, with commas
```

I am searching for easy way (linux tools) to add quotas to last column:

```
column1, column2, column3
1, 03-12-2017, "some text, with commas"
```

Have you any ideas ?

Comment: can there be lines with more than 3 commas? also, you are expected to show what you've tried.. see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed '1!{s/\([^,]*,[^,]*, \)/\1"/;s/$/"/}'
```

- `1!` means the block shouldn't be applied to the first line
- `[^,]*` means as many non-comma characters as possible
- The first two columns (i.e. non-comma characters, comma, space, non-comma characters, comma, space) are remembered in `\1` and replaced by themselves followed by `"`
- end of line `$` is replaced by `"`

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is a great tool to manipulate delimited files:

```
awk -F",[ ]*" '
    NR==1 { print; next }
          { for(i=1; i<NF-1; i++) { printf("%s, ", $i) } printf("\"");
            printf("%s, ", $(NF-1));
            printf("%s\"\n", $NF) }' file
```

- `-F",[ ]*"`           - use "comma followed by zero or more spaces as the field delimiter; you can use `-F", "` if you are sure that all delimiters have a single space after comma

Answer (score 1):

If it can been more than 3 fields,
You can try this awk

```
awk -F, '
  NR!=1{
  $NF=$NF"\""
  a=b=$(NF-1)
  sub(/[^[:blank:]].*/,"",a)
  sub(/^[[:blank:]]*/,"",b)
  $(NF-1)=a "\"" b
  }1' OFS=, infile
```

Or this sed

```
sed -E '
  1b
  s/([[:blank:]])([^,]*,[^,]*$)/\1"\2"/
  ' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "}NR>1{$3="\""$3;$4=$4"\""}1' file
```

output adds double quotes to second row last 2 fields

```
column1, column2, column3
1, 03-12-2017, "some text, with commas"
```